# How to refer to object from what im using function

Tags: ruby

I'm learning ruby, and I'm writing a simple text game where we are fightning versus opponents. I have a class "Hero", where I have code like this

```
  def attack(enemy)
    enemy.hp -= attack_damage
    puts enemy.name + " HP:" + enemy.hp.to_s
    enemy.attack(# This is the place where I need to refer to object from what I'm calling this method #)
  end
```

when I want to make a fight I just create new hero, and enemy, but I can't use recursion, because i dont know how to refer to object, as i said, so the fight lasts only 1 hit

```
abundzu = Hero.new("abundzu", 100, 25, 5)
herr = Hero.new("herr", 50, 25, 5)
abundzu.attack(herr)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `self`:

```
def attack(enemy)
  enemy.hp -= attack_damage
  puts "#{enemy.name} HP: #{enemy.hp}"
  enemy.attack(self)
end
```